# Engine has switched to 'python' because numexpr does not support extension array dtypes

Tags: python, pandas

I am running a program with streamlit and I get an error message that I would like to manage.
I must add that the program is running right except this error message.

This is the error messages:

```
Engine has switched to 'python' because numexpr does not support extension array dtypes. Please set your engine to python manually.
```

```
RuntimeWarning: Engine has switched to 'python' because numexpr does not support extension array dtypes. Please set your engine to python manually.
  list_fonds = list_fonds.query("NomTypeFinancialObject=='Fonds' and dtRet>@date_deb_an and GroupeCat_Specific_Dynamic!='FCPR'")
```

Comment: Quick Duck Duck Going gets me https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/29027